# Embedded TomEE in Grails 3.3 application

Tags: tomcat, gradle, grails, apache-tomee

My Grails 2.4 application works fine on Tomcat and TomEE.

Recently I upgraded it to Grails 3.3.*. Now it still works fine when deployed to standard Tomcat, but fails to start on TomEE. The first couple of error messages are:

```
05-Aug-2019 16:03:00.588 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy servlet XXXXXXX has no servlet-class defined and is not a subclass of Application
05-Aug-2019 16:03:00.660 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/XXXXXXX]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Can't find resource for class asset.pipeline.grails.AssetProcessorService#grailsLinkGenerator. (No provider available for resource-ref 'null' of type 'grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator' for 'XXXXXXX.Comp1855693364'.)
```

I read somewhere that I should replace dependency on standard Tomcat with one on TomEE, but I cannot find how to do that. My current dependency on Tomcat (in Gradle build) is:

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

which I changed from:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

without visible effect.

What need to be done for my Grails3.3.* web app works on TomEE?

TomEE info:

```
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.201 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.41 (7.0.6)
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.201 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server built:          May 4 2019 09:17:16 UTC
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.201 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server number:         8.5.41.0
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.201 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Name:               Linux
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.202 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Version:            3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.202 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Architecture:          amd64
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.202 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Java Home:             /usr/local/jdk/jre
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.202 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Version:           1.8.0_212-b03
05-Aug-2019 16:02:47.202 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Vendor:            Eclipse OpenJ9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a conf/exclusions.list containing two lines, "default-list" and "grails". If not enough, maybe add a scan.xml to ensure not EE classes are not scanned (see https://tomee.apache.org/refcard/refcard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tomitribe (TomEE support group) confirmed that there are too many conflicts between Spring/Grails and TomEE. Their suggestion is to do not use them together. Instead, use standard Tomcat with Grails.